# How to add custom claim in django rest_framework_simple_jwt?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

Their official doc only shows implementation for [class based views](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html).

How to get this done for a function, ie. Refreshtoken.for_user()?

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def get_tokens_for_user(user):

    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    
    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

[Snippet from here](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html). This only shows how to create token manually.

I know using `pyjwt` would make life simpler but there will be another workaround for blacklisting.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I always followed is here. You may see that the `Token` class in `rest_framework_simplejwt` implemented `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`. So easily you can add a claim to your token.

You have to make a customer serializer that will extend the `TokenObtainSerializer` class. See the code for a better understanding:

**serializers.py:**

```py
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainSerializer):
    token_class = RefreshToken

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

        refresh["my_claim"] = "value" # here you can add custom cliam

        data["refresh"] = str(refresh)
        data["access"] = str(refresh.access_token)

        return data
```

And then create a view that will extend the `TokenViewBase` class:

**views.py**

```py
class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenViewBase):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
]
```

Here we go, Done.

After doing those steps and decoding the access token you will find something link this:

```
{
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": 1651785191,
  "iat": 1651784891,
  "jti": "8432cb561ef0467e909e4a4c05234b71",
  "user_id": 1,
  "my_claim": "value"
}
```

For more, you can see this [repo](https://github.com/milon19/django-custom-auth-backend). Here I did a project following the `rest_framework_simplejwt` package for learning and understanding the custom authentication backend.

Comment: The question clearly asks for an approach while dealing with function. And also you are adding data to the payload and this is not the case. The case is adding custom claim, i.e., adding custom field within the encoded token, not as a response of json key value pair.

Comment: I said that you will get your claim `after decoding` the encoded token. It will not add the field with the response. The response will be the same as before, in this case, the access token and refresh token. 

And for the function base, it will be the same way. `refresh["something"] = "something"`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to add custom claims in the manually generated token is:

**serializers.py**

```
# User Serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('password',)
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from .serializers import UserSerializer

def get_tokens_for_user(user):
  refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

  #Add custom claims
  refresh["user"] = UserSerializer(user).data

  return {
      'refresh_token': str(refresh),
      'access_token': str(refresh.access_token),
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
refresh["first_name"] = str(user.first_name) //any field or data
```

To add custom fields in decode of access token , we add like this
[image]